# HTML : Change table color using getElementById

Tags: html, getelementbyid

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = "";
        var HTML = "";
        HTML = "<table border=1><tr><td id='1'>1</td><td id='2'>2</td><td id='3'>3</td></tr></tabele>";
        document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = HTML;

        document.getElementById('2').innerHTML = '<td id=1 bgcolor="red">5</td>';
    </script>
</BODY>
```

I make table using Javascript.
I want to change some cell's background color, so I use getElementById.
I can change its text value, but I cannot change cell's background color.
Anyone know about this problem??

Answer (score 11):

If you want to do this in Javascript without jQuery just use this :

```
document.getElementById('2').style.backgroundColor="red";
```

With the property `style` of an object returned with `getElementById()` or `getElementByClass()` you can change the CSS style.

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbLac/)

Answer (score -1):

you want to change background color of some cell...?? Don't get me started on your codes now.
What happened to the good old

`$('selector').css('backgroundColor','red')`

The selector here refers to the html element you want to select. In your case it must select the table cells.

And why are you still using bgcolor?? What's wrong with css??? Grab some new books.

Comment: it uses the queryselectorall, according to my knowledge